# Linux mount как это работает?

Tags: linux

```
/dev/sda1       49858048   9735340  37566972  21% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             8154448    344236   7810212   5% /run/shm
none              102400        72    102328   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6      179620256 132090216  38382752  78% /home
```

Как получается, что home это подкаталог / но у него больше места. Как вообще  работает mount на уровне ядра линукса?

Comment: там больше места, потому что это другой физический диск. а ядро просто знает (по этой самой таблице mount) при обращении по какому пути какой диск надо читать

Comment: Обратите внимание, что любой путь это просто условность. так же как и условность буквы дисков в dos/windows. по большому счету никакой разницы в понимании что `C:\ ` и `D:\ ` это разные диски и в понимании, что `/C` и `/D` могут быть разными устройствами нет. А если вместо одной буквы разрешить более длинные имена `/home/...` ...

Comment: мое объяснение - папка (каталог, директория) это просто специальный файл, где написано адрес, где искать файлы для нее. И при должной поддержке операционной системы, этот адрес может быть каким-угодно (другой диск, ssh, специальный модуль ядра, ftp, usb-mtp). А корень (папка '/') это спец папка от ядра (нужна точка отсчета, точка опоры).

Comment: @KoVadim, в каталоге `/` нет ничего «специального». в примере из вопроса туда смонтирована файловая система с первого раздела блочного устройства `/dev/sda`.

Comment: просто подумайте о том, куда монтируется собственно `/`

Comment: Спасибо вам, я похоже понял суть. @KoVadim скопируйте ваши комментарии в ответ, я отвечу его как верный, он помог мне больше всего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нижеприведенное объяснение сильно упрощенное, но для начального понимания достаточно.

Папка (каталог, директория) это просто специальный файл, где написано адрес (в каком то виде), где искать файлы этой папки. И при должной поддержке операционной системы и файловой системы, этот адрес может быть каким-угодно (место на диске, другой диск, ssh, специальный модуль ядра, просто кусок памяти, ftp, usb-mtp - главное, что бы был драйвер/модуль, который мог отдавать операционной системе список файлов, содержимое и разную метаинформацию).

А корень (папка '/') это спец папка от ядра (нужна точка отсчета, точка опоры), куда все монтируется. В Windows этому как бы отвечает "мой компьютер" (или "этот компьютер" или как он там сейчас называется).

вывод команды mount показывает привязки каталогов к дереву каталогов (иначе нужно было бы каждую файловую систему учить, как связываться с другой)